# Impyla UDF - where is numba.ext.impala?

Tags: python, impala, numba

Does anyone know where I can find the numba impala extension (`numba.ext.impala`) mentioned in this impyla example: https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/tree/master/examples/iris_model?  I've done a good bit of searching on github as well as google with no luck.

Also, I opened an issue here: https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/issues/72, but no responses yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I received from the impyla github repo in case anyone runs across this (this may change over time of course):

> Note that the UDF stuff has only been tested with `numba<=0.13.4`, and
>   I'd suggest using that specific version. It will definitely fail with
>   the latest version of numba.
>
> Otherwise, no need for `numba.ext.impala`, and it actually no longer
>   exists. You should use `impala.udf.xxx`